# Get MongoCluster Primary with C# Drver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I connect with the following code to a mongo database.
Then i iterated through the server descriptions of the cluster but the state is always "disconnected" but when i look with tools like monogchef i can see that all server are connected and there is one primary and all others are secondaries

```
 var client = new MongoClient(conString);
 var db = client.GetDatabase("admin");
  foreach (var server in client.Cluster.Description.Servers)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(server.State); // Always returns disconnected.
        }
```

How can I read who is the primary and when has been the last election?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it.

Have to make a dummy request then i find the data under

```
server.ReplicaSetConfig.Primary
```